# Clarification about the Schengen 90/180 rule: non-consecutive 90 days

Tags: schengen

I would like to have further clarification on this topic. I am a US citizen who goes in and out of the Schengen area regularly. For instance, 10 days each month, but every once in a while 30 consecutive days in Schengen. I have not stayed more than 90 total days during a 180 day period. Given that I do not reach 90, I understand there would be no need to have a waiting period to re-enter. I can continue to regularly come and go, as long as I watch out for the 90 days within a revolving 180. Is this correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is correct, assuming you're counting the 180-day period correctly. For example, if you're spending ten days every month, you will have to be careful about how many days fall between two thirty-day visits.